# Mongoose/MongoDB - Delete and Insert as one transaction

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to delete certain set of documents in the mongo collection and insert new records, in case if the insert fails I want to rollback the delete. Basically, it is either both or none. Someone know what is the best approach for this. I'm using mongoose and nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use promises. Insert one more field to your schema like isDeleted. When you delete some document set it to true and in the success of promise of delete, if the document successfully inserted delete that record permanently if you want.

Like this

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(query)
.exec()
.then(
     // write your insert logic here
     db.collection.insert(query)
    .exec()
    .then()
    .catch(
      //if anything goes wrong set isDeleted
       //to false again. 
    )
)
.catch()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a 'hidden' flag, then set the flag to true on some records insert new ones then depending on insert failure or success delete hidden objects or unhide them

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a "***Transaction***".
A transaction is a unit of work, composed of a series of operations that you want either to succeed together, or fail together when one or more of the operations fail.

The following example considers an operation of placing an order in an e-commerce site, where you are interested in performing various operations in a ***transaction***:

- Insert one order in the orders collection
- Substract 'quantity' from the corresponding items in the inventory collection.
- Add a reference to the order in current customer orders, in the customers collection.

You want all three operations to be performed 'as a block', and if something fails, none of them will be performed, keeping the database status as it was before.

The steps you need to perform are:

1. Start a session
2. Start a transaction, specifying transaction options
3. Perform data operations in the same session
4. Commit a transaction, or cancel it if the driver encounters an error
5. End a session

And here the sample code you could use:

```
async function placeOrder(client, cart, payment) {
  const transactionOptions = {
    readConcern: { level: 'snapshot' },
    writeConcern: { w: 'majority' },
    readPreference: 'primary'
  };
  const session = client.startSession();
  try {
    session.startTransaction(transactionOptions);
    const ordersCollection = client.db('testdb').collection('orders');
    const orderResult = await ordersCollection.insertOne(
      {
        customer: payment.customer,
        items: cart,
        total: payment.total,
      },
      { session }
    );
    const inventoryCollection = client.db('testdb').collection('inventory');
    for (let i=0; i<cart.length; i++) {
      const item = cart[i];
      // Cancel the transaction when you have insufficient inventory
      const checkInventory = await inventoryCollection.findOne(
        {
          sku: item.sku,
          qty: { $gte: item.qty }
        },
        { session }
      )
      if (checkInventory === null) {
        throw new Error('Insufficient quantity or SKU not found.');
      }
      await inventoryCollection.updateOne(
        { sku: item.sku },
        { $inc: { 'qty': -item.qty }},
        { session }
      );
    }
    const customerCollection = client.db('testdb').collection('customers');
    await customerCollection.updateOne(
      { _id: payment.customer },
      { $push:  { orders: orderResult.insertedId }},
      { session }
    );
    await session.commitTransaction();
    console.log('Transaction successfully committed.');
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof MongoError && error.hasErrorLabel('UnknownTransactionCommitResult')) {
      // add your logic to retry or handle the error
    }
    else if (error instanceof MongoError && error.hasErrorLabel('TransientTransactionError')) {
      // add your logic to retry or handle the error
    } else {
      console.log('An error occured in the transaction, performing a data rollback:' + error);
    }
    await session.abortTransaction();
  } finally {
    await session.endSession();
  }
}
```

The following link explains in detail the use of transactions in nodejs and mongodb:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/transactions/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks for improving your post. In addition to a description, please add an example of how to perform a transaction. Much if the purpose is that the answer still helps people if the link no longer works.